# Wedge Patch Position Not Updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to shift the position of a `matplotlib.patches.Wedge` by modifying its `center` property, but it does not seem to have any effect.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

tmp = patches.Wedge([2, 2], 3, 0, 180)
ax.add_artist(tmp)
tmp.center = [4, 4]  # Try to move!

ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
print(tmp.center)
plt.show()
```

Produces the following:

[image: sad]

Which is clearly incorrect.

A similar approach functions fine for `matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

tmp = patches.Ellipse([2, 2], 2, 2)
ax.add_artist(tmp)
tmp.center = [4, 4]  # Try to move!

ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
print(tmp.center)
plt.show()
```

[image: ellip]

And `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` (with the change from `center` to `xy`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

tmp = patches.Rectangle([2, 2], 3, 2)
ax.add_artist(tmp)
tmp.xy = [4, 4]  # Try to move!

ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
print(tmp.xy)
plt.show()
```

[image: rect]

I thought it might be `Wedge` utilizing `xy` rather than `center`, but the `Wedge` object does not have an `xy` attribute. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to `update` the properties of your `Wedge`:

```
tmp.update({'center': [4,4]})
```

As you see, the method accepts a dict that specifies the properties to update.

[image: result]